# how could i remember the root of the tree after creation

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

i was trying to read a tree from a text file using recursive. I have debugged every step inside the function, and it returned a valid root pointer. But when I set the return node pointer to root in the main function, the root is an null pointer. why is that?

```
node *treeRead(FILE *fp) {
    char readIn[100];
    char questionOnode[40];
    char content[100];
    char *get = NULL; // the return value for fgets()
    node *ptr;

    ptr = NULL;
    get =fgets(readIn,sizeof(readIn),fp);
    if (  get == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else {
        ptr = malloc ( sizeof(node));

        sscanf(readIn,"%[^:]:%[^\n]",questionOnode,content);

        // if the line started with "question"
        if ( !strcmp(questionOnode,"question")){
            //fill ptr from the input line read in above
            ptr->question = content;
            printf("question:%s\n",content);
            //read its children
            ptr->yes = treeRead(fp);
            ptr->no = treeRead(fp);
        }
        else{//the line started with "object"
            ptr->name = content;
            printf("object:%s\n",content);
            ptr->yes = NULL;
            ptr->no = NULL;
        }
        return ptr;
    }

int main()
{
   // here omit the open file parts and node structure definition,
   // fp is the file pointer to the text file.
   node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
   root = treeRead(fp);

}
```

How could i get the root of the tree?

Comment: Are you saying the address returned by `treeRead(fp)` is `NULL`, therefore `root == NULL`? Or are you saying the values of `root->question` is `NULL`?

Comment: The `{bracing}` in your incomplete example does not work. As far as I see, not all paths in the function return a value. Please post a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of skipping the bits that you think work.

Comment: If you mean `root` is `NULL` then probably `ptr` never gets allocated. Probably, the first `else` is never executed.

Comment: Be pedantic: check the result of `malloc` and the result of `sscanf`.

Comment: I was trying to say, the return pointer inside the function was alright. But when i set it to root, root pointer got NULL. @alvits

Comment: There is something wrong whenever i assign treeRead(..) to a node pointer, like the 'root = treeRead(fp)', 'ptr->yes = treeRead(fp)' and 'ptr->no = treeRead( fp)'. All the node pointers get NULL value after the assignment.

Comment: You haven't proven that `ptr` has the correct memory allocation before returning from `treeRead(fp)`. What you have proven is that `treeRead(fp)` has correct logic based on the printouts. Are you aware that you are pointing `char * ptr->question` to `char content[100]` which is a local variable? Same with `char * ptr->name`. Do you know what will happen as soon as the function returns? All its local variables will be gone. Fix those 2 before you begin to suspect `treeRead(fp)`.

Comment: @alvits Thank you for your reply. I know that if the function returns, all the variable inside the function will be free. But here ptr is a pointer that I have allocated memory space for it. It contains the name value. So i guess, when the pointer is returned by the function, the c first creates a copy of the return value. After assigns it to the root, the copy will be free.

Comment: You have not shown the definition of the structure. Assigning memory location of a local variable to `ptr->name` and `ptr->question` is simply wrong. If `ptr->name` and `ptr->question` are character arrays then you just screwed up `ptr`. `gcc -Wall -Wextra` will give you warnings.

Comment: @alvits No, it didn't give me any error. Sorry, I still didn't get it the reason why I can't assign the variable content to ptr->name. Because of the lifetime? Here I list the definition of the structure:typedef struct node{
    char *name;
    char *question;
    struct node *yes;
    struct node *no;
}node;

Comment: You are not assigning the content of the variable. You are assigning the address of the variable. The correct way is to allocate memory for `ptr->name` `ptr->name=malloc(strlen(content)+1);` then copy the string `strcpy(ptr->name, content);`.

Comment: @alvits aah, I see. Since ptr->question and ptr->name are char pointers, they will point to addresses that have already be free after function completes. Is that right? Then how could I fix this? Changing the question and name into char arrays rather than pointers?

Comment: You can use either char array or char pointer. Just as long as you copy the contents into it instead of pointing it to the address of a local variable. See my previous comment.

Comment: @alvits Thanks sooooooooooo much .

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your program calls `fopen()`. Therefore you tree will be invalid as you will never read any nodes.

(Rereading - your program won't actually compile. Please try harder)

Comment: Perhaps he opens the file in the hidden section... He actually says `//here omit **the open file parts** and node structure definition`

Comment: @abligh i do have the fopen(...), and it worked successfully. i just didn't copy that part for you.